# Kafka pause & resume message loss

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, resume, pause

Hi I have recently created a program to extract and save data to kafka.

For testing, I put data from 1 to 20000 in kafka, read the record with the following code and print it.
If there is no pause&resume, the output is normal from 1 to 20000.
But When run pause&resume, there was an empty number in the print.

In my program pause&resume often used.
so It seems to affect the offset value.

Have you ever experienced the same thing?

```
consumer.handler(record -> {
        try {
            JsonObject json = record.value();
            final String value = json.getString("data_source");
            System.out.println(value); //value=record.Number

            count++;                
            if (count%1000==0) {
                consumer.pause();
                System.out.println("Pause & Resume >>>>>>>>");
                count=0;
                consumer.resume();
            }
```

> result : [1,2,3,(empty num),10,11,12,~~(empty num)~,19998,19999,20000]

Comment: Which Kafka version you are using?

Comment: I use kafaka version :  2.12-1.1.0 & vertx-kafka-client 3.5.3.